# Text Adventure, load method works until user inputs a direction to a different room?

Tags: java

I have just recently been trying to make a Text Adventure type game. I've got most of the framework layed out - I just need to finish debugging. Right now my problem is that when you run the game as a new user and save the game, it works perfectly. Even when you load it it works until you try to leave the room.

```
Please enter a username: test
Creating game . . .

You are in a dark room.
You see a book and a key.
It looks like you can go forwards. 
>get book
You pick up the book.
>save
Saved successfully
```

That part is no problem, this part is.

```
What is your username: test
Loading game . . .

You are in a dark room.
You see a key.
It looks like you can go forwards. 
>get key
You pick up the key.
>forwards
You can't do that.
>exit
Are you sure? (y/n): y
Thanks for playing.
```

As you can see When I load the previous game the console shows me what exits there are, I can see my inventory has the book, and I can get the other item. I just cannot figure out how to get the game to send me to the next room based upon what exit you are trying to go out of.

Here is my code that I feel goes with this question. I am sorry in advance for the sloppiness and inefficiency of my code. I am still learning and trying to figure out the best way to fix it. Any advice or tips from you guys will be much appreciated.

load method

```
    public void load(Player p, Room r, World w, Inventory inven) throws Exception
    {
        Sleep s = new Sleep();
        long time = 3000;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your username?: ");
        String username = in.next();
        String name;
        int currentRoomNumber;
        String currentRoomDescription;
        ArrayList<String> currentRoomItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> currentRoomExits = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> inv = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(username + ".txt");
        if(f.exists())
        {
            try
            {   
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                name = (String)ois.readObject();
                currentRoomNumber = (int)ois.readObject();
                currentRoomDescription = (String)ois.readObject();
                currentRoomItems = (ArrayList<String>)ois.readObject();
                currentRoomExits = (ArrayList<String>)ois.readObject();
                inv = (ArrayList<String>)ois.readObject();
                ois.close();

                p.setUserName(name);
                r.setRoomNumber(currentRoomNumber);
                r.setRoomDescription(currentRoomDescription);
                r.setItems(currentRoomItems);
                r.setExits(currentRoomExits);
                inven.setInv(inv);
                System.out.println();
                w.CurrentRoom(currentRoomNumber, currentRoomDescription, currentRoomItems, currentRoomExits);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where my code gets bad. This is part of my CurrentRoom method. It is found in my world class with the rest of the other rooms. This was the only way I could think of to save the progress in the game.

CurrentRoom

```
void CurrentRoom(int roomNumber, String roomDescription, ArrayList<String> items, ArrayList<String> exits)
    {
        Room CurrentRoom = new Room();
        String i1 = ""; // I use these to get the Strings out of the items Array.
        String i2 = "";
        String i3 = "";
        String e1 = "";//I was going to use these to get the exit Strings out of the exits Array
        String e2 = "";
        String e3 = "";
        String e4 = "";
        CurrentRoom.setRoomNumber(roomNumber);
        CurrentRoom.setRoomDescription(roomDescription);

        if(items.size() == 1)
        {
            i1 = items.get(0);
        }
        //I initialize all of my items like this

        if(exits.size() == 1)
        {
            e1 = exits.get(0);
        }
        else if(exits.size() == 2)
        {
            e1 = exits.get(0);
            e2 = exits.get(1);
        }
        else if(exits.size() == 3)
        {
            e1 = exits.get(0);
            e2 = exits.get(1);
            e3 = exits.get(2);
        }
        else if(exits.size() == 4)
        {
            e1 = exits.get(0);
            e2 = exits.get(1);
            e3 = exits.get(2);
            e4 = exits.get(3);
        }
        CurrentRoom.setExits(exits);

        while (true) 
        {
            if(items.size() > 0)
            {
                if(items.size() == 1)
                {
                    if (input.equals("get " + i1) && items.contains(i1)) 
                    {
                        items.remove(i1);
                        this.inventory.add(i1);
                    } 
                }//I use this plus other if statements to tell if the player is trying to get the items.
                //I tried copying the above code that worked for the items and using it on the exits, but I figured out it does not work the same for the exits.                
            }
            input = getInput();
        }

    }
```

The problem is that I store my exits in an array. I now know this does not really work at all, because there is no way when I load the exit array back in for the game to know which exit really leads to which room. I looked up some ways on this website and saw something about using

```
HashMap<String direction, Room neighbor>
```

I could not figure out how to really use the above HashMap. What is the best way to fix this so that my exits will load correctly? I have an example room I am using to test my code. If I need to add it here let me know, thanks.

Comment: good effort, though a more narrowed-down code-set may be more useful for you to get help

Comment: I'm sorry what exactly do you mean?

Comment: "go" is not implemented inside your `while(true)`, right?

Comment: Sorry dude, can't read all this code right now but I recommend this link here, perhaps you can use this web approach as reference to solve this current_room tracking/persistence issue that you are facing: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex52.html

Comment: @ZachSutherland what Coffee means and theMarceloR also indicates: it's quite a lot of code to dig through which might keep many from even trying to help. If you can reduce the amount of code to check without leaving out relevant parts you're more likely to get help.

Comment: No, my other rooms are set up like "void roomOne" then all the code inside it so if the user types forwards my code to go to the next room currently is "this.roomTwo". After i implemented the save/load method I realized that will not work

Comment: Okay I'll edit the code now

Comment: It is pretty **bad** to have a Method called "CurrentRoom" __and__ a class called "CurrentRoom" __and__ an instance of that class inside that method called also the same.

Comment: I only have a method called CurrentRoom, It is inside my World class. I have a Room class where the CurrentRoom method gets all of its data from.

Comment: OK, but you call the instance of "Room" "CurrentRoom" inside "CurrentRoom" method. That's at least confusing. But that just as a side-note. You don't implement the "go" command. So how can you expect it to be executed?

Comment: That is how all my rooms are which I want to fix but I will get to that later. Thank you for the constructive criticism though. So when you say the "go command" do you mean the user putting something like "go forwards" or is there a "go" command in java.

Comment: I mean your command to enter a different room. Some edits ago it was "go forward". I didn't see it being implemented in the `CurrentRoom` method.

Comment: I took it out because that was not working. I have some methods in my code that accepts certain words. So "forwards" and "go forwards" are the same thing. I do not have it set up to realize that when you say "go forwards" though that it knows what room you are supposed to go.